Why first criteria only executed when filtering the rows by matching two columns in Python Pandas Dataframe
I have below code to filter out rows of earliest year and month in the data. I used the logical operator '&' as in the Method 1 segment of this below code. But Method 1 segment of below code filter out rows if first criteria condition met no matter second criteria met or not as it seems. Method 2 gives the correct output.
For your info the columns "Year" and "Month" in excel file is in "General" format. And I tried Original_File_df.query method also.
import pandas as pd
Original_File_df = pd.read_excel(open("6 Months.xlsx", "rb"), sheet_name = 0)
New_Data_File_df = pd.read_excel(open("1 Month.xlsx", "rb"), sheet_name = 0)

#Method 1 Start
Original_File_YMMin = pd.to_datetime(Original_File_df["Year"].astype(str) + "-" + Original_File_df["Month"].astype(str), format='%Y-%m').min()
Original_File_df = Original_File_df[(Original_File_df["Year"] != Original_File_YMMin.year) & (Original_File_df["Year"] != Original_File_YMMin.month)]
#Method 1 End

#Method 2 Start
Original_File_df["YearMonth"] = pd.to_datetime(Original_File_df["Year"].astype(str) + "-" + Original_File_df["Month"].astype(str), format='%Y-%m')
Original_File_YMMin = Original_File_df["YearMonth"].min()
Original_File_df = Original_File_df[Original_File_df["YearMonth"] != Original_File_YMMin]
#Method 2 End

Original_File_df = Original_File_df._append(New_Data_File_df, ignore_index=True)
print(Original_File_df)



Given an expression !x & !y, this can be converted to !(x | y) just by boolean algebra. So what you're asking is really "drop if the year is 2023 or the month is 10". (Eg https://www.boolean-algebra.com/?q=eyh4eSl9.)
Why is this true? Well, let's walk through the example of year 2023 and month 11:

Keep [this is implicit to the subset operation] if A(the year is not 2023) and B(the month is not 10)...
A(Year is not 2023) -> False
B(Month is not 10) -> True
False and True -> False

Alternatively, in Python:
(A := 2023 != 2023) & (B := 11 != 10)  # False. Nb `and` short-circuits
A  # False
B  # True

Because only Trues are kept, year 2023 and month 11 is dropped. (All the negations are very confusing.)
